# How to make array in array without key?

Tags: php

I wanna make array like

```php
[
  ['first', 1],
  ['second', 2],
  ['third', 3]
]
```

My current code is

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $map = [$value['name'], $key];
    $map = implode(',', $map);
    $result[] = $map;
}
dd($result);
```

What I got is

```php
[
    (int) 0 => 'first,1',
    (int) 1 => 'second,2'
]
```

Comment: Just remove `$map = implode(',', $map);`

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Its is easier if

```
$array1 = array('first'=>1);
$array2 = array('second'=>2);
$array3 = array('third'=>3);
$result = array($array1,$array2,$array3);
var_dump($result);
echo "<BR><BR>";

$count = 1;
$result = array();
$keys = array('first','second','third');
foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    $map = array();
    $map[$key] = $count++;
    $result[] = $map;
}
var_dump($result);
```